# GIT-quotients of projective-over-affine varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, geometric-invariant-theory

**Given an action of a reductive group on a projective-over-affine variety, what are the conditions for its GIT-quotient to be again a projective-over-affine?**

There is a very nice set of slides about GIT quotients, and it asserts the quotient in my question is indeed projective-over-affine when a very ample associated line bundle is chosen; see the page 13 of the linked pdf.

[Mayrand - Symplectic reduction and geometric invariant theory](https://www.math.toronto.edu/mayrand/cms-mini-course.pdf)

But it does not precisely cite a book or a paper, and **I am looking for a (friendly) reference answering my question.**

I am also wondering  whether, if the action is semi-stable for a choice of a linearization, then the quotient is always projective-over-affine.

I would appreciate any comments!